# Which VS 2008 project for using MVC and WorkFlow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, workflow

In Visual Studio 2008 after I add the Feb 2010 SharePoint extensions, I see project templates for Workflow (eg., State Machine Workflow Library) and under C#/Web a project for ASP.NET MVC Web Application.

If I'd like to do a State Machine WorkFlow using MVC which should I choose and which additional modifications do I need to do ?

(I'm new to ASP.NET)

Thanks

Bruce

Comment: What are you trying to do? SharePoint and MVC don't mix.. SharePoint and workflows do.

Answer (score 1):

You'll add both. The MVC project will be a UI tier, and the WorkFlow project will be a business tier. You'll add a reference to the WorkFlow project in the MVC project.

Comment: I'm interested in how these two layers would interact. Would you mind providing a link or two to resources about this please. My google foo isn't very good today.